# AngularJS evaluate an interpolation expression without printing to screen

Tags: angularjs

I have an expensive function call that gets called once per loop, but I would like to set the return value of that to be a temporary variable that can be used directly within the loop.

This works by setting `{{ val=fn(...) }}`, but it also prints to the screen. Is it possible to do this without printing the value?

I've tried using one set of curly braces `{}` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into "filters" or possibly doing the work in your JS code instead of the view?

Comment: I haven't considered a filter. Its such a basic operation and I would like to see if it's possible to do without using a filter.

Comment: In my experience, I have found that to not be very possible. Learning how to build filters, while it seems like overkill initially, will keep the templates clean of JS, which is the 'way' of AngularJS...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a temporary variable, call a method when you need the value, and in this method, use a cached version of the result, or call your expensive method if the cached version is null/undefined. It will only call your expensive function once per iteration, and it won't call it if it's not needed. It won't print it unless you want to. Because each iteration of a ng-repeat spawns a new scope, each iteration will start with an empty cache.

e.g.:

```
$scope.cache = null
$scope.getValue = function() {
  if (!this.cache) { // use typeof if 0 or false or empty string is valid!
    this.cache = myExpensiveFunc()
  }
  return this.cache
}
```

Not 100% sure $scope.cache = null will be initialized for each scope of the iteration, you may need to check if 'this' hasOwnProperty 'cache' in getValue. So in your view, you only reference getValue() when you need to.

HTH!

edit: cache on scope, not in controller.